# Button+Spinner [android]

Tags: android, spinner

I used a spinner and a button inside a tab of my application

but, when I assigned a onClicklistner for my button

the application crashes.

i used

```
myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, 
         int i,longlng) {
    }
});
```

for my spinner and

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do some work
    }
});
```

for my Button. the application works fine once I use only on listner!!!!

please help,thanx

Answer (score 0):

try this

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

value.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View V, int pos,
            long arg3) {
                                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are initialized the any view on activity ,firstly initialized the all component which you are using in xml

use this line for button in activity

```
mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

then it would be work.